# Possible ransomware

Tags: encryption, malware

I have an SSD with Ubuntu on a partition and /home on another partition. I also have another  HDD  installed on the system. The  SSD is connected through PCIe so the hard drive access red led doesn’t blink when the SSD is accessed. On the HDD there are exclusively documents, videos, music and images.  Yesterday I turned on the computer and without do anything more, the access red led stared blinking continuously. Being afraid the HDD may be being encrypted, I turned off the computer about 2 minutes after I turned it on (the red blinking never stops). There is another explanation for such a continuous access red blinking?

I am scared.

Thank you!

Comment: paranoid much? By the way: turning  a system of while the hdd is active is a good way of killing the hdd. And if it was encrypting the disk even worse: you would have killed access to the system. "There is another explanation for such a continuous access red blinking?" There are so freaking many possible things but I will pick one. But oh let's say how about ... updating the locate database for one? Your systems likely does that once a week and it would be indexing your documents.

Comment: The best defense against ransomware is ordinary, plain old, everyday backups.

Comment: @Rinzwind Your comment is the answer I was looking for. You are right on everything: I am paranoid and yes, indexing is a clever explanation. I am now relieved. I have turned on my computer and it is working as good as before. Thank you very much. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @CarlosFreites thing is. You can get infected by you need to go out of your way to do so. Stick to the normal places for software: ubuntu software center you can assume our repositories are 100% safe (track record of USC is perfect up to now). Launchpad PPA's: not perfect but if you look up the owner of a PPA and check its history you can be assured those are safe. Same for larger websites (apache, mysql). Do not add random PPA's from the web. Do not install from source (tar.gz) unless from the website of a large company.

Comment: ... use a fairly good password for admin. And above all: don't piss of random people on the net.  As long as Windows systems are easier to infect all of us Linux users will not be as much as a target unless someone actually picks a specific person as a target.

Answer (score 2):

A blinking HDD LED is not an indication that your computer is infected.

I would suspect some background process is doing some work.  Some great information about how to figure out which one is available here:

https://superuser.com/questions/50091/how-do-i-find-out-what-processes-are-accessing-the-hard-disk-in-a-gnu-linux-base

To summarise, you can use `iotop` to monitor which processes are accessing the disk - it won't separate your HDD and SDD but if your system is otherwise completely idle it may still help.

Comment: Oh thanks, I did so and found that a program named compiz was active, I found what it does and I wrongly determine that it can not be the reason of my HDD access. Now, thanks to Rinzwind I know that is probable that compiz was indexing it.